PPT VBA - Making selected objects the same size as the first object
I'm trying to make all selected objects/shapes the same size as the first selected object on PPT VBA. Tried the below code but doesn't work.
Sub ResizeShape()
Dim NumShapes As Integer
Dim Shp As Variant
NumShapes = ActiveWindow.Selection.Count
If NumShapes < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select at least one shape."
    Exit Sub
End If

Get dimensions of the first selected shape
Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
With Shp
    BaseShpHeight = .Height
    BaseShpWidth = .Width
End With

For i = 2 To NumShapes
    Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)

        With Shp
            .Height = BaseShpHeight
            .Width = BaseShpWidth
        End With
Next i
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If

End Sub

Do you get an error? What does not work?

For starters, always choose Debug | Compile VBA Project before trying to run your code. Until you can compile without errors, there's no point in trying to run the code. Because it won't run.
Also, ALWAYS declare ALL your variables.
Put Option Explicit at the top of each module to have VBA force you to do this.
And declare variables appropriately. For shape variables, declare them as Shape rather than variant; VBA's intellisense will help you with shape properties/methods that way. And generally, counters and indices should be declared as Long.
Here's a fixed version, with comments added to explain why I made the changes I did.
Sub ResizeShape()

Dim NumShapes As Long   ' not Integer
Dim Shp As Shape        ' not Variant
' Declare the other variables you've used
Dim BaseShpHeight As Single
Dim BaseShpWidth As Single
Dim i As Long

' NumShapes = ActiveWindow.Selection.Count
NumShapes = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count

If NumShapes < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select at least one shape."
    Exit Sub
End If

' The next line was supposed to be a comment
' I've marked it as such
' Get dimensions of the first selected shape

Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With Shp
    BaseShpHeight = .Height
    BaseShpWidth = .Width
End With

For i = 2 To NumShapes
    Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)

        With Shp
            .Height = BaseShpHeight
            .Width = BaseShpWidth
        End With
Next i
    
' There's no IF statement that corresponds to this
' Commenting it out
'    Else
'        MsgBox "Error"
'    End If
End Sub

